# Maintain custom url in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I’ve been trying to do this for two weeks and I am still stuck. Now, my situation is this:

With no user session started, if I enter this url in the brower: `http://localhost.../something?a=1&b=2` it shows the subscription with the attributes a = 1 and b = 2. Everything OK.

If I edit something of the subscription everything goes OK, but the problem is that the url changes to `http://localhost.../subscription/id`.

What I want is that when I modify something in the subscription the url must be `http://localhos.../something?a=1&b=2`  instead of the `http://localhost.../subscription/id`.

routes.rb

```
 …
 match "/something" => "subscriptions#show"
 …
```

subscription_controller.rb

```
…
def show
  @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id] || Subscription.find_by_token_and_networkId!(params[:t], params[:nwk]))
…
```

I don’t want to became the /subscription/id url useless because I want to access it from another part of the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller update method, try this before the closing tag:

```
redirect_to :back
```

Currently, you probably have something like:

```
redirect_to @subscription
```

Comment: Sorry, that was the solution. I mess my files :) Thank you!